# I can't create or download a system on AVD manager(Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk, java-5, avd-manager

I installed android studio, I wanted to create a virtual device but I I got this error message "Installation did not complete successfully. See the IDE log for details" how can I fix this pls? android-studio avd-manager java sdk jdk1.5

Comment: Did you see the IDE log for details? This is pretty much unanswerable, because there is something specific to your environment. You need to do some research and then share what you find if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I can't upload the pic because I'm new here. U have a facebook page?  I can add you up and explain better

Comment: Don't upload pictures. Just put the text of relevant details in the body of the question with an [edit]. SO is not a threaded forum, and you might be able to get one-on-one help via the chat functionality (though not from me) but first people are going to want to see a clear idea of what is going on. See [ask]. The idea is you tell us what you are trying to do, show your research, and then explain what results you got.